# How much dry soil before the waterline does Angelica need?

Tags: watering

I'm trying to grow angelica, but every few days it seems to getting rid of "old leaves". What am I doing wrong to kill off new growth?

Right now I have it in a 5 gallon bucket with no holes to let the water out.

Comment: How big is this plant you are trying to grow in a 5 gallon bucket without drainage?  Even plants that love bogs need drainage, circulation of water freshened with oxygen.  Sounds as if you need to go plant in your garden area with lots of sucky mud.  5 gallon bucket with garden bog soil and water, not even aquatic plants could handle that. The only oxygen transfer is that top surface which is not much.  Anaerobic.  Roots need oxygen.

Comment: the plant is less than the size of my hand, the bucket is almost full of water, and soil,  I have no garden area with a lot of suckymud, and am trying to mimic it with the bucket, since it was a water garden society plant.

Comment: What did the water garden society tell you to do?  You have to have circulation or your plant won't make it. The garden's sucky mud would have circulation or you would smell it.